# Convert array of objects by date with total

Tags: javascript

This is the array of objects the I want to convert and get the total amount and clicks

```
[
  {
    date: "2020-05",
    amount: 1000,
    clicks: 15
  }, {
    date: "2020-05",
    amount: 500,
    clicks: 10
  }, {
    date: "2020-06",
    amount: 2000,
    clicks: 20
  }
]
```

I want the array of objects above to be like this (with total amount and clicks)

```
{
  amount: [
    {
      date: "2020-05",
      value: 1500
    }, {
      date: "2020-06",
      value: 2000
    }
  ],
  clicks: [
    {
      date: "2020-05",
      value: 25
    },
    {
      date: "2020-06",
      value: 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code you've tried? Where is the issue?

Comment: that groupBy accepted answer is a complete waste of time

Comment: `let result = Object.values(input.reduce((a, {date, amount}) => {
  a[date] = a[date] || {date};
  a[date].amount = (a[date].amount || 0) + amount;
  return a
}, {}));` where `input` is the data you have

Comment: thanks a lot @JaromandaX this is exactly what I need